# Fixed search box and table header, scrolling body

Tags: css

I have the following code for an address book. I'd like to have the search box and table header fixed allowing the table body to scroll up (or behind). I've tried several different CSS coding techniques without success. Can anyone point me to a CSS-only solution? The HTML/CSS code follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ccffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Directory</h1>
<!-- <p>Search</p>   -->
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Street</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>163</td>
    <td>Canal Lane</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>916-806-9999</td>
    <td>jim@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jacquelyn</td>
    <td>Abel</td>
    <td>4551</td>
    <td>Paso Lane</td>
    <td>999-999-9208</td>
    <td>999-999-3835</td>
    <td>he51@comcast.net</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Deborah Kay</td>
    <td>Affal</td>
    <td>335</td>
    <td>Suez Lane</td>
    <td>555-555-4897</td>
    <td>555-555-3773</td>
    <td>debb@hotmail.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Emily</td>
    <td>Aguate</td>
    <td>3943</td>
    <td>River Lane</td>
    <td>444-444-2951</td>
    <td>444-444-0514</td>
    <td>erag@hotmail.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Anthony (Tony)</td>
    <td>Alba</td>
    <td>4449</td>
    <td>Red Lane</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>777-777-7778</td>
    <td>tony35@yahoo.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Amador</td>
    <td>Alcan</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>Izmal Place</td>
    <td>222-222-2002</td>
    <td>333-333-3418</td>
    <td>abab@7lakes.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ofelia</td>
    <td>Alcan</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>Izmal Place</td>
    <td>234-234-2002</td>
    <td>234-234-7151</td>
    <td>ofof@7lakes.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sherry</td>
    <td>Allala</td>
    <td>3910</td>
    <td>Euboea Lane</td>
    <td>5657-567-9331</td>
    <td>567-567-9427</td>
    <td>sherr11@att.net</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Lori</td>
    <td>Anders</td>
    <td>3905</td>
    <td>ADel Paso Lane</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>789-789-4784</td>
    <td>mags3@yahoo.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Peggy</td>
    <td>Angert</td>
    <td>3924</td>
    <td>Pozzlo Lane</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>321-321-3494</td>
    <td>peggy00@yahoo.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Angty</td>
    <td>3924</td>
    <td>Pozzaler Lane</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>678-678-3003</td>
    <td>peter5657@hotmail.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Caryne</td>
    <td>Angler</td>
    <td>4436</td>
    <td>Sea Lane</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>987-987-6605</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Neata</td>
    <td>Anton</td>
    <td>3973</td>
    <td>Don Lane</td>
    <td>456-456-8711</td>
    <td>456-456-4744</td>
    <td>nea456t@sbcglobal.net</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what are you tired or search??

Comment: https://colorlib.com/wp/css3-table-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Put the table's head and the search box in a separate `div` and set it's `position` attribute to `fixed`.

```
// I'm assuming that you've assigned the div a class called
// .th_div
.th_div { position: fixed; }
```

An element with `position: fixed;` is positioned relative to the **viewport**, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt reply!  I've tried to implement your suggestion, but I didn't get it to work.  Below is the edited code.  Maybe I've missed something???

Comment: I tried the changes to the CSS and HTML, but it didn't work.  How do I share my edited code so you can see?  I tried to paste it here, but I received an error message that it was too long.

Comment: You have posted enough code. Did you try my suggestion after I made my last edit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the jQuery call that's preventing this from working.  I'm not skilled enough to dig into that (yet).  If there's a simple solution to this I'd appreciate knowing what it is.  If not, I'll learn more about jQuery.  Thanks!